# Asignar color a un button dependiendo de su valor - CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

Teniendo estos dos botones:

```
<button type="button" id="boton_uno" class="boton-estado btn-default">Boton 1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" id="boton_dos" class="boton-estado btn-default">Boton 2</button>
```

dependiendo de si el valor es 0, 1 ó 2, pues el color varía:
0 - rojo 
1 - verde
2 - naranja

En HTML si el color sería rojo: `<button type="button" style="background:red">`, ¿pero como sería dependiendo del valor que tenga...?

Ejemplo: el estado inicial es 0, pregunto en un modal si queremos cambiar el estado a estado=1(color del boton verde) o estado=2(color del boton naranja)

Comment: a cual valor te refieres? No está muy claro tu pregunta

Comment: Al que tome el boton.

Comment: Las preguntas no se pueden formular asi. El valor donde esta. Esta en javascript? esta en un input? de donde sale. Desarrolla la pregunta.Y a poder ser, haz un fiddle con tu ejemplo, los datos pueden estar modificados, pero un ejemplo siempre ayuda, sobre todo a la hora de entender y resolver la consulta

Comment: Al margen de esta pregunta, a la que le falta información como dice Mikel, has hecho varias preguntas últimamente y en ninguna has aceptado respuestas y lo único que haces es repreguntar continuamente en los comentarios. ¿Nada de lo que te han dicho te ha servido?

Comment: Estoy dando votos positivos a las respuestas pero al no tener suficiente reputación no deben contabilizar al público.

Comment: Sí, creo que necesitas 15 puntos para poder votar pero me refiero a respuestas aceptadas, si alguna respuesta que te han dado te ha servido  marca el check ✔️ que hay debajo del número de los votos, así los demás saben que ya has solucionado tu problema y si otros tienen la misma duda encontraran también una solución.

Comment: Entendido. Acabo de dar los likes que creo oportunos, y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes añadir o quitar estilos con js en la respuesta del modal:

```
var boton = document.querySelector("#boton_uno");
if(estado==1){
  boton.style.backgroundColor = "green";
} else {
  ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu solución fue muy apropiada y legible.

Answer (score 3):

Supongo que te refieres a que vas a hacer algo como `<button value="1">` no?

Si es así, la solución es este CSS:

```
button[value='0'] {
  color: red;
}

button[value='1'] {
  color: green;
}

button[value='2'] {
  color: orange;
}
```

Aquí tienes un fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zevane/x5asLtb1/

Comment: Gracias, tu solución fue bastante buena. En cuanto tenga permisos de votos, (más reputación, te votaré), aun soy novato.